# How to get first file extension in string using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get first file extension in string using php.

now i use this code.

```
<?php
$string = "aaa.jpgbbb.pngccc.jpg";
if( strpos( $string, $needle ) !== false ) {
    list($string) = explode('.png',$string);
    echo $string.".jpg";
}
?>
```

My code only check file extension in string. but can not get first file extension. How can i do ?

.
.

For this string first file extension is `jpg`.

```
$string = "aaa.jpgbbb.pngccc.jpg";
```

.
.

For this string first file extension is `gif`.

```
$string = "aaa.gifbbb.pngccc.jpg";
```

.
.

For this string first file extension is `png`.

```
$string = "aaa.pngbbb.pngccc.jpg";
```

Comment: all your extension will come only three letters?

Comment: This makes no sense. Why does `$string` contain multiple filenames crammed together like this?

Comment: @ ceejayoz - multiple filenames i get from srcset tag sir.

`<img srcset="https://stillmed.olympic.org/media/Images/OlympicOrg/News/2018/03/02/2018-03-02-Figure-Skating-Hanyu-Fernandez-thumbnail.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&amp;fit=around|768:337&amp;crop=768:337;*,*, https://stillmed.olympic.org/media/Images/OlympicOrg/News/2018/03/02/2018-03-02-Figure-Skating-Hanyu-Fernandez-thumbnail.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&amp;fit=around|1536:674&amp;crop=1536:674;*,* 2x" alt="">`

Comment: But a `srcset` has them in comma-separated format, like `aaa.png, bbb.png, ccc.jpg`. Why not use that?

Comment: @ Nawin - not always sir, i want to store file extension set into array for detect sir.

Comment: You want only first extension?

Comment: This is a pretty glaring example of an XY problem. How and why have you ended up with a string containing multiple concatenated filenames when your actual use-case is a `srcset` attribute?

Comment: @ Nawin - yes....

Comment: @Nawin - not work when ` $string = "www.xxx.com/aaa.jpgbbb.pngccc.jpg";`

Comment: @mamongmamiw Now you're just being silly. Use the **actual** `srcset` value and explode it on the `,` character. This entire question has an absurd premise.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "aaa.gifbbb.pngccc.jpg";
$pattern = '|\.([^\.]+)$|';
preg_match ( $pattern , $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
die;
```

Try this one